# node - how to differentiate between errors coming from Readable and Writable streams when using pipes?

Tags: node.js, pipe, pipeline

I pipe a custom Readable stream to a custom Writable stream. The `pipeline` / `pipe` methods get the `error` event of both the Readable and Writable.

How do I know whether the error I got from the pipe is coming from the Readable or from the Writable?

I can listen to the Readable\Writable on error event, but the same error event is received from the pipe itself, so I get it twice or 3 times, and then it's hard to compare between what I got from them and what I got from the pipe. I hope there is a better way to approach it.

With the example below, uncomment the first comment to get the error from the Readable and the second comment to get the error from the writable.

```
const { Readable, Writable, pipeline } = require('stream');
const fs = require('fs/promises')
const { promisify } = require('util')

const customReadable = new Readable({ objectMode: true, read(){} });
customReadable.push({ name: 'file1', content: 'hello world' });
customReadable.push({ name: 'file2', content: 'hello world2' });
// customReadable.destroy(new Error('Error from Readable'));

class CustomWritable extends Writable {
  constructor() {
    super({ objectMode: true });
  }
  async _write(obj, _, callback) {
    try {
      // throw new Error('Error from Writeable');
      await fs.writeFile(obj.name, obj.content);
      callback();
    } catch (err) {
      callback(err);
    }
  }
}

const pipelinePromise = promisify(pipeline);

pipelinePromise(customReadable, new CustomWritable())
  .then(() => {
    console.log('completed successfully');
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('pipeline found an error', err);
  })
```

Comment: Good luck with this.  Error handling with streams and piping is quite a mess.  I thought the `pipeline()` function was supposed to fix some of it, but I've not found that to be the case.  If I need bulletproof error handling on a piping scenario, I put separate error listeners on both the read and write stream, log them all and devise some way to communicate back whichever error occurs first.

Comment: FYI, isn't it a bit ironic that you use the promisified `fs.writeFile()` and `try/catch` and `async/awit` only to convert its result back into a callback.  `fs.writefile(obj.name, obj.content, callback)` with the regular `fs` object would be a heck of a lot simpler.

Comment: Actually `pipeline` is pretty useful, especially when the piping more than two streams, this way no need to attach an error event for the first ones. In my case it doesn't really help coz as you said, it seems like I have to listen to each one of the streams :(  About the `async/await`, yes you're right :) I just took it from a real usage where inside the `try` there is a lot of async processing.

Comment: Yeah, well that's the theory of the usefulness of `pipeline()`, but if it doesn't do the appropriate error handling, then it's really missing the whole point.  IMO, streams from the very beginning have never been designed well for error handling and `.pipe()` just swept all sorts of errors under the covers.  If, heaven-forbid, you need to actually do something when there's an error like clean up partially written files, it's even worse.  This part of nodejs streams seems way, way under-engineered and is now mostly codified in "compatibility" boxes where fixing things would break existing code.